# Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects Plugin broke Sonar 4.4

Tags: sonarqube

I have recently upgraded Sonar to latest version 4.4.
Everything worked very well yesterday. Today, when I try to install the Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects Plugin and restart the Sonar service (on Windows Server 2012), it fails repeatedly.

I went to the Extensions/Plugins folder and manually removed the Analysis Bootstrapper jar file, then launch Sonar as console mode, it still fails.

Does anyone have similar problems? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the error that I can read from sonar.log file:

```
2014.09.22 16:08:25 ERROR [o.s.s.p.PlatformServletContextListener]  Fail to start server
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ES update could not be completed within: 30000ms
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ES update could not be completed within: 30000ms
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:130) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:118) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbSession.select(DbSession.java:117) ~[sonar-core-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.BatchSession.select(BatchSession.java:54) ~[sonar-core-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.rule.db.RuleDao.synchronizeAfter(RuleDao.java:97) ~[RuleDao.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.synchronize(IndexSynchronizer.java:61) ~[IndexSynchronizer.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.execute(IndexSynchronizer.java:51) ~[IndexSynchronizer.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents$1.doPrivileged(ServerComponents.java:690) ~[ServerComponents$1.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:43) ~[DoPrivileged.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.executeStartupTasks(ServerComponents.java:687) ~[ServerComponents.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:126) ~[Platform.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:122) ~[Platform.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81) ~[Platform.class:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:54) ~[PlatformServletContextListener.class:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ES update could not be completed within: 30000ms
    at org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.enqueue(IndexQueue.java:124) ~[IndexQueue.class:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:59) ~[sonar-core-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.BatchSession.commit(BatchSession.java:170) ~[sonar-core-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbSession.enqueue(DbSession.java:52) ~[sonar-core-4.4.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.rule.db.RuleDao$1.handleResult(RuleDao.java:101) ~[RuleDao$1.class:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.callResultHandler(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:306) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.storeObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:300) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:292) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:266) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:239) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:150) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:60) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:73) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doQuery(BatchExecutor.java:87) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:137) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:96) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:77) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:128) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
2014.09.22 16:08:25 INFO  [sql]  0ms Executed SQL: SELECT p.id as "id", p.rule_id as "ruleId", p.name as "name", p.param_type as "type", p.default_value as "defaultValue", p.description as "description" FROM rules_parameters p, rules r WHERE p.rule_id=r.id AND r.plugin_name=? AND r.plugin_rule_key=? - parameters are: <findbugs>, <DM_CONVERT_CASE>
2014.09.22 16:08:25 INFO  [sql]  203ms Executed SQL: SELECT r.id, r.plugin_rule_key as "ruleKey", r.plugin_name as "repositoryKey", r.description, r.status, r.name, r.plugin_config_key as "configKey", r.priority as "severity", r.is_template as "isTemplate", r.language as "language", r.template_id as "templateId", r.note_data as "noteData", r.note_user_login as "noteUserLogin", r.note_created_at as "noteCreatedAt", r.note_updated_at as "noteUpdatedAt", r.characteristic_id as "subCharacteristicId", r.default_characteristic_id as "defaultSubCharacteristicId", r.remediation_function as "remediationFunction", r.default_remediation_function as "defaultRemediationFunction", r.remediation_coeff as "remediationCoefficient", r.default_remediation_coeff as "defaultRemediationCoefficient", r.remediation_offset as "remediationOffset", r.default_remediation_offset as "defaultRemediationOffset", r.effort_to_fix_description as "effortToFixDescription", r.tags as "tagsField", r.system_tags as "systemTagsField", r.created_at as "createdAt", r.updated_at as "updatedAt" FROM rules r WHERE r.plugin_name=? AND r.plugin_rule_key=? - parameters are: <findbugs>, <OS_OPEN_STREAM>
2014.09.22 16:08:25 INFO  [sql]  203ms Executed SQL: select c.id, c.kee as kee, c.name as name, c.parent_id as parentId, c.characteristic_order as characteristicOrder, c.enabled as enabled, c.created_at as createdAt, c.updated_at as updatedAt from characteristics c WHERE c.id=? and c.enabled=1 - parameters are: <33>
2014.09.22 16:08:25 INFO  [sql]  0ms Executed SQL: select c.id, c.kee as kee, c.name as name, c.parent_id as parentId, c.characteristic_order as characteristicOrder, c.enabled as enabled, c.created_at as createdAt, c.updated_at as updatedAt from characteristics c WHERE c.id=? and c.enabled=1 - parameters are: <27>
2014.09.22 16:08:25 INFO  [sql]  0ms Executed SQL: SELECT p.id as "id", p.rule_id as "ruleId", p.name as "name", p.param_type as "type", p.default_value as "defaultValue", p.description as "description" FROM rules_parameters p, rules r WHERE p.rule_id=r.id AND r.plugin_name=? AND r.plugin_rule_key=? - parameters are: <findbugs>, <OS_OPEN_STREAM>
2014.09.22 16:08:26 INFO  [sql]  31ms Executed SQL: SELECT r.id, r.plugin_rule_key as "ruleKey", r.plugin_name as "repositoryKey", r.description, r.status, r.name, r.plugin_config_key as "configKey", r.priority as "severity", r.is_template as "isTemplate", r.language as "language", r.template_id as "templateId", r.note_data as "noteData", r.note_user_login as "noteUserLogin", r.note_created_at as "noteCreatedAt", r.note_updated_at as "noteUpdatedAt", r.characteristic_id as "subCharacteristicId", r.default_characteristic_id as "defaultSubCharacteristicId", r.remediation_function as "remediationFunction", r.default_remediation_function as "defaultRemediationFunction", r.remediation_coeff as "remediationCoefficient", r.default_remediation_coeff as "defaultRemediationCoefficient", r.remediation_offset as "remediationOffset", r.default_remediation_offset as "defaultRemediationOffset", r.effort_to_fix_description as "effortToFixDescription", r.tags as "tagsField", r.system_tags as "systemTagsField", r.created_at as "createdAt", r.updated_at as "updatedAt" FROM rules r WHERE r.plugin_name=? AND r.plugin_rule_key=? - parameters are: <findbugs>, <CN_IDIOM_NO_SUPER_CALL>
2014.09.22 16:08:26 INFO  [sql]  31ms Executed SQL: select c.id, c.kee as kee, c.name as name, c.parent_id as parentId, c.characteristic_order as characteristicOrder, c.enabled as enabled, c.created_at as createdAt, c.updated_at as updatedAt from characteristics c WHERE c.id=? and c.enabled=1 - parameters are: <28>
2014.09.22 16:08:26 INFO  [sql]  0ms Executed SQL: select c.id, c.kee as kee, c.name as name, c.parent_id as parentId, c.characteristic_order as characteristicOrder, c.enabled as enabled, c.created_at as createdAt, c.updated_at as updatedAt from characteristics c WHERE c.id=? and c.enabled=1 - parameters are: <27>
2014.09.22 16:08:26 INFO  [sql]  16ms Executed SQL: SELECT p.id as "id", p.rule_id as "ruleId", p.name as "name", p.param_type as "type", p.default_value as "defaultValue", p.description as "description" FROM rules_parameters p, rules r WHERE p.rule_id=r.id AND r.plugin_name=? AND r.plugin_rule_key=? - parameters are: <findbugs>, <CN_IDIOM_NO_SUPER_CALL>
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Can you try to delete the "<SONAR_HOME>/data/es" folder and restart again?

Comment: Yes, I did. But that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

This error has gone away after a server reboot.
I highly suspect that Java Automatic Update must have occurred.